# Heroku server down after uploading first change

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

I've just set up a Facebook app on Heroku, and after a lot of trouble, I finally got it uploaded succesfully via "git push heroku master". After that, the site won't load. Try yourself, at: https://electric-galaxy-6836.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Run: `heroku logs` and tell us what you see.

Comment: @AmokraneChentir It looks like the server restarts a couple of times a day.
This is the error that happens everytime:
[error] server
reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
GET electric-galaxy-6836.herokuapp.com
/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=0

Comment: I am also having the same problem!